# How to link a table cell?

Tags: html, css, background, href

I need to set a link on master page file. So i set a background image for a table column (`<td>`) and give some font as "home" separately. Now i setup "onclick" event and redirect it to the page from `<td>`. But it gives some spaces bottom to the image on browser. So the link(hand symbol) starts from white spaces below to the button image. I checked all the margin setups, padding etc. But it wont works. So now i decided to set a href for background image. Is it possible or any other way to rectify this problem? i found some helps in internet. But i dont know how to use this code. i attached the help code with this post.

**My code:**

```
<tr style="height:44px;">
            <td id="Homebutton" runat="server" style="height: 44px; width: 101px; cursor: pointer;"
                class="menubuttonhome" align="center" onclick="navigate(id)" onmouseover="this.className='menubuttonhomefocus'"
                onmouseout="this.className= 'menubuttonhome'">
                Home
            </td>
</tr>
```

**css File**

```
.menubuttonhomefocus
        {
            background-image: url('Images/homebuttonfocus.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            vertical-align: top;
            color: White;
            padding-top: 11px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
```

**Help code from internet**

```
a.particular-link {display: block; /* or inline-block; I think IE would respect it since a link is an inline-element */
                   background: #fff url(path/to/image.gif) top left no-repeat; 
                   text-align: center;
                   line-height: 50px; }
```

Comment: The description is very confusing and seems to postulate something impossible (you cannot make a background image link, though you can assign a background image to a link). Please reformulate, and explain why you cannot use a simple link `<a href=...>...</a>`.

Comment: If i make it to as simple href link.. it leaves some spaces below the image. That means when we click in empty space, it redirects to other page. That's why i want it to background image only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<tr>
  <td id="Homebutton" runat="server" class="menubutton">
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
td {
  padding: 0;
}

.menubutton > a {
  display: block;
  width: 101px;
  height: 44px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 11px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Homebutton {
  background-image: url(Images/homebutton.png);
}

#Homebutton:hover {
  background-image: url(Images/homebuttonfocus.png);
}
```

Note for hover effects you just need to use the `:hover` pseudo-class.

Btw. the space at the bottom of the image is reserved for text. I.e. if you wrote some text it would appear below the image.

Comment: Thank you very much dude. Then another issue. my total height of the table is 86 px. i separate it into two rows the first row is 42px. then the second row is 44 px. My home button picture is in second row. Picture size is also 44 px. But it leave some space in second row ( below the home button image) that is the problem i faced. But now i reduced the height from 44 to 35. Now it works well. How it is happen dude? That is the space for text or any other problem?

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the space below to the image?

Comment: That's the space reserved for the text. E.g. if you set 'font-size' to 'line-height' to 0 it would also be gone.

Comment: Thank you for let me know Sebastian. Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem. CSS (especially CSS3) can achieve very much, which was not possible before or you needed workarounds/hacks. To learn more about it I suggest you read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As Jukka already mentioned it's not possible to set a link to the background image applied via CSS.

You should really use an `<a>` tag instead. The trick is to force the height of the link to the height of the image.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image link</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      td {
        padding: 0;
      }
      a {
        display: block;
        height: 89px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: blue;"><a href="#asdf"><img src="http://getfirebug.com/img/firebug-logo.png" style="background-color: yellow;"/></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Though I also want to note that you should **never** use tables for layouting. There are [several good reasons](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html) not to use table layouts. Instead you can use e.g. `<div>`s, `<header>`s and `<section>`s.

Comment: I understand dude. But how can i enter the text "home" on that image? Will you have some idea for that? plz help me

Comment: Please refer my above code. In this the home word that is separated from background image. That's why i set the button image as background image. Is there any alternate ideas?

Comment: Thank You for spending me your valuable time.